# How to use Boost library 1.55.0 to create a shared memory using a matlab application

Tags: matlab, boost, shared-memory, mex

I'm trying to use boost library 1.55.0 to create a shared memory.I have a example.cpp file which creates boost shared memory. Mexing of this file is successful,but throws the following exception while debugging "MATLAB.exe has triggered a breakpoint".Is this exception because of the version of the boost being incompatible with the matlab version? How to resolve this
`/*  File    : sfun_counter_cpp.cpp
*  Abstract:
*
*      Example of an C++ S-function which stores an C++ object in
*      the pointers vector PWork.
*
*  Copyright 1990-2000 The MathWorks, Inc.
*

### */

```
#include "iostream"   
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp> 
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>  
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>

typedef struct
{
 int           outGate;
 unsigned int  outPin;
 int           inGate;
 unsigned int  inPin;   
} wire;

typedef struct
{
unsigned int  gateType;
unsigned int  inPins;
unsigned int  outPins;
std::vector<wire>  inWires;
std::vector<wire>  outWires;
} gate;

std::vector<gate> gates;
wire wiredata;
gate gatedata;

class  counter {
    double  x;
public:
    counter() {
        x = 0.0;
    }
    double output(void) {
        x = x + 1.0;
        return x; 
    }
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { // use the C fcn-call standard for all functions  
#endif       // defined within this scope                     

#define S_FUNCTION_LEVEL 2
#define S_FUNCTION_NAME  sfun_counter_cpp

/*
* Need to include simstruc.h for the definition of the SimStruct and
* its associated macro definitions.
*/
#include "simstruc.h"

/*====================*
* S-function methods *
*====================*/

/* Function: mdlInitializeSizes ===============================================
* Abstract:
*    The sizes information is used by Simulink to determine the S-function
*    block's characteristics (number of inputs, outputs, states, etc.).
*/
static void mdlInitializeSizes(SimStruct *S)
{
    /* See sfuntmpl_doc.c for more details on the macros below */

    ssSetNumSFcnParams(S, 1);  /* Number of expected parameters */
    if (ssGetNumSFcnParams(S) != ssGetSFcnParamsCount(S)) {
        /* Return if number of expected != number of actual parameters */
        return;
    }

    ssSetNumContStates(S, 0);
    ssSetNumDiscStates(S, 0);

    if (!ssSetNumInputPorts(S, 0)) return;

    if (!ssSetNumOutputPorts(S, 1)) return;
    ssSetOutputPortWidth(S, 0, 1);

    ssSetNumSampleTimes(S, 1);
    ssSetNumRWork(S, 0);
    ssSetNumIWork(S, 0);
    ssSetNumPWork(S, 1); // reserve element in the pointers vector
    ssSetNumModes(S, 0); // to store a C++ object
    ssSetNumNonsampledZCs(S, 0);

    ssSetOptions(S, 0);
}

/* Function: mdlInitializeSampleTimes 
=========================================
* Abstract:
*    This function is used to specify the sample time(s) for your
*    S-function. You must register the same number of sample times as
*    specified in ssSetNumSampleTimes.
*/
static void mdlInitializeSampleTimes(SimStruct *S)
{
    ssSetSampleTime(S, 0, mxGetScalar(ssGetSFcnParam(S, 0)));
    ssSetOffsetTime(S, 0, 0.0);

}

#define MDL_START  /* Change to #undef to remove function */
#if defined(MDL_START) 
/* Function: mdlStart 
=======================================================
* Abstract:
*    This function is called once at start of model execution. If you
*    have states that should be initialized once, this is the place
*    to do it.
*/
static void mdlStart(SimStruct *S)
{
    ssGetPWork(S)[0] = (void *) new counter; // store new C++ object in 
the
}                                            // pointers vector
#endif /*  MDL_START */

/* Function: mdlOutputs =======================================================
* Abstract:
*    In this function, you compute the outputs of your S-function
*    block. Generally outputs are placed in the output vector, ssGetY(S).
*/
static void mdlOutputs(SimStruct *S, int_T tid)
{

    using namespace boost::interprocess;
    counter *c = (counter *) ssGetPWork(S)[0];   // retrieve C++ object from
    shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory");
    //create the shared memory 
    managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536); 

    //create the allocators for the struct elements to be accessed as 
vectors
    typedef allocator<gate, 
managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>gate_alloc;
    typedef allocator<wire, 
managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>inwire_alloc;
    typedef allocator<wire, 
managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>outwire_alloc;

    //create a boost vector with an associated allocator to it
    typedef vector<gate, gate_alloc>gate_vec;
    typedef vector<wire, inwire_alloc>inwire_vec;
    typedef vector<wire, outwire_alloc>outwire_vec;

    //Initialize shared memory STL-compatible allocator
    const gate_alloc alloc_inst(segment.get_segment_manager());
    const inwire_alloc alloc_inst1(segment.get_segment_manager());
    const outwire_alloc alloc_inst2(segment.get_segment_manager());

    //construct the segment for pushing the data into it
    gate_vec *gate_data = segment.construct<gate_vec>("gatedata") 
(alloc_inst);
    inwire_vec *inwire_data = segment.construct<inwire_vec>("inwiredata")  
        (alloc_inst1);
    outwire_vec *outwire_data = segment.construct<outwire_vec> 
("outwiredata") 
        (alloc_inst2);


    //push the data into the vectors
    wiredata.inGate = 10;
    wiredata.inPin = 2;
    wiredata.outGate = 1;
    wiredata.outPin = 3;
    inwire_data->push_back(wiredata);
    outwire_data->push_back(wiredata);

    gatedata.gateType = 1;
    gatedata.inPins = 2;
    gatedata.outPins = 3;
    gate_data->push_back(gatedata);


    real_T  *y = ssGetOutputPortRealSignal(S,0); // the pointers vector 
and use
    y[0] = c->output();                          // member functions of 
the
}                                                // object

/* Function: mdlTerminate 
=====================================================
* Abstract:
*    In this function, you should perform any actions that are necessary
*    at the termination of a simulation.  For example, if memory was
*    allocated in mdlStart, this is the place to free it.
*/
static void mdlTerminate(SimStruct *S)
{
    counter *c = (counter *) ssGetPWork(S)[0]; // retrieve and destroy C++
    delete c;                                  // object in the 
termination
}                                              // function
/*======================================================*
* See sfuntmpl_doc.c for the optional S-function methods *
*======================================================*/

/*=============================*
* Required S-function trailer *
*=============================*/

#ifdef  MATLAB_MEX_FILE    /* Is this file being compiled as a MEX-file?*/
#include "simulink.c"      /* MEX-file interface mechanism */
#else
#include "cg_sfun.h"       /* Code generation registration function */
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // end of extern "C" scope
#endif
```

`
this is the sfunction which I have to mex , debug and run .Though the mexing of the above code snippet is successful ,it throws an exception "MATLAB.exe has triggered a breakpoint" while debugging.

Answer (score 2):

I can give you an example. Unfortunately I cannot test it with windows, but I have tested it on a UNIX system. The main idea is the same. In this case it is shared memory from an external binary to a Matlab mex function.

The external binary is:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

const std::string payload("SHARED MEMORY CONTENT");

int main(void) {
  shared_memory_object shm(open_or_create, "memory4mat" ,read_write);
  shm.truncate(payload.size());
  mapped_region mem(shm, read_write);
  std::memcpy(mem.get_address(), payload.c_str(), mem.get_size());

  do {
    std::cout << '\n' << "Press a key to continue...";
  } while (std::cin.get() != '\n');

  shared_memory_object::remove("memory4mat");

  return 0;
}
```

while the mex function is:

```
#include "mex.hpp"
#include "mexAdapter.hpp"
#include "MatlabDataArray.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp"
#include "boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp"

using namespace boost::interprocess;

class MexFunction : public matlab::mex::Function {
public:
    void operator()(matlab::mex::ArgumentList outputs, matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs) {
      matlab::data::ArrayFactory factory;

      shared_memory_object shm(open_only, "memory4mat", read_only);
      mapped_region mem(shm, read_only);

      std::string payload(static_cast<const char *>(mem.get_address()), mem.get_size());
      outputs[0] = factory.createCharArray(payload);
      outputs[1] = factory.createScalar<int16_t>(mem.get_size());
    }
};
```

it uses the [C++ Interface and Data API for Matlab](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/Cpp-api.html). To compile the two example you need to add the boost include directory as compiler options (shared memory is a header only feature in boost).

The external binary [create a shared memory](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html) that contains the string `"SHARED MEMORY CONTENT"`, and waits an enter from the user to remove the shared memory object.

The mex files opens the shared memory if exist (if the shared memory do not exist an error is reported and handled in Matlab, which is one of the reasons why I prefer C++ api) and copy its content in a Matlab char array. The function returns two values, the first is the content of the shared memory, the second is the length of the shared memory (the mapper uses all the memory, set with truncate).

This simple example uses only basic features and should work on Unix and Windows system, but again I cannot test on win.

### A more complete example

Let's try with a more complete example about shared memories and Matlab Mex files. Let us write a very simple external binary that allows us to create/delete/read/write a shared memory. This binary has a lot of stuff hardcoded for simplicity, such as the name of the memory file (`"shmem"`):

```
// File: share_server.cpp
// g++ share_server.cpp -o share_server
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

static const std::size_t size = 20;
static const std::size_t wsize = 15;
static const char name[6] = "shmem";
static const char input[wsize] = "write in share";
char output[size];

inline void printHelp() {
  std::cout << "Options:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "  n) open a new 'shmem' memory" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "  d) delete a 'shmem' memory" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "  r) read from 'shmem' memory" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "  w) write to 'shmem' memory" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "  x) Exit" << std::endl;
}

inline void cmd_createShare() {
  try {
    shared_memory_object sm(create_only, name, read_write);
    sm.truncate(size);
    std::cout << "Shared object created" << std::endl;
  } catch(std::exception & e) {
    std::cout << "Create Error :: " << e.what() << std::endl; 
  }
}

inline void cmd_deleteShare() {
  try {
    shared_memory_object::remove(name);
    std::cout << "Shared object deletetd" << std::endl;
  } catch(std::exception & e) {
    std::cout << "Delete Error:: " << e.what() << std::endl; 
  }
}

inline void cmd_readShare() {
  try {
    shared_memory_object sm(open_only,  name, read_only);
    mapped_region sh_mem(sm, read_only);
    std::string ret(static_cast<const char *>(sh_mem.get_address()), sh_mem.get_size());
    std::cout << ret << std::endl;
  } catch(std::exception & e) {
    std::cout << "Read Error:: " << e.what() << std::endl; 
  }
}

inline void cmd_writeShare() {
  try {
    shared_memory_object sm(open_only,  name, read_write);
    mapped_region sh_mem(sm, read_write);
    std::memcpy(sh_mem.get_address(), input, wsize);
    std::cout << "Write completed" << std::endl;
  } catch(std::exception & e) {
    std::cout << "Read Error:: " << e.what() << std::endl; 
  }
}
```

we can write 3 mex files (using the C++ api) in order to interact with the shared memory. The first one, the simplest, reads the content of the shared memory as a string and returns it to the Matlab workspace. The interface in Matlab syntax is something like:

```
function [value, read_size] = read_share(share_name)
  ...
end
```

and the C++ implementation is the following:

```
// File: read_share.cpp
#include "mex.hpp"
#include "mexAdapter.hpp"
#include "MatlabDataArray.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>

#include "boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp"
#include "boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp"

using namespace boost::interprocess;
using namespace matlab::data;

class MexFunction : public matlab::mex::Function {
private:
  std::shared_ptr<matlab::engine::MATLABEngine> engine;
  ArrayFactory factory;

  void throwError(std::string errorMessage) {
    engine->feval(matlab::engine::convertUTF8StringToUTF16String("error"),
            0, std::vector<Array>({ factory.createScalar(errorMessage) }));
  }

  uint64_t read_shared_memory(const std::string & name, std::string & ret_value) {
    try {
      shared_memory_object sm(open_only,  name.c_str(), read_only);
      mapped_region sh_mem(sm, read_only);
      ret_value += std::string(static_cast<const char *>(sh_mem.get_address()), sh_mem.get_size());
      return ret_value.size();
    } catch(std::exception & e) {
      throwError(std::string("Reading error: ") + std::string(e.what()));
    }
    return 0;
  }

  void checkArguments(matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs, matlab::mex::ArgumentList outputs) {
    if (inputs.size() != 1)
      throwError("Input must be of size 1");
    if (inputs[0].getType() != ArrayType::CHAR)
      throwError("First element must be a matlab char array");
    if (outputs.size() > 2)
      throwError("Too many outputs (required 1)");
  }

public:
  MexFunction() { 
    engine = getEngine();
  }

  void operator()(matlab::mex::ArgumentList outputs, matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs) {  
    checkArguments(inputs, outputs);
    const CharArray name_array = std::move(inputs[0]);
    std::string name = name_array.toAscii();
    std::string ret_string("");
    uint64_t ret_size = read_shared_memory(name, ret_string);
    outputs[0] = factory.createScalar(ret_string);
    outputs[1] = factory.createScalar<uint64_t>(ret_size);
  }  
};
```

The second mex file is the write operation. It takes two input: the name of the shared memory and the string to write inside the memory. The mex checks the maximum size of the shared memory and stores no more than the available space. The function returns the bytes written in the The interface for the write function is something like:

```
function written_size = write_share(share_name, string)
  ...
end
```

and the implementation is:

```
// File: write_share.cpp
#include "mex.hpp"
#include "mexAdapter.hpp"
#include "MatlabDataArray.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <exception>

#include "boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp"
#include "boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp"

using namespace boost::interprocess;
using namespace matlab::data;

class MexFunction : public matlab::mex::Function {
private:
  std::shared_ptr<matlab::engine::MATLABEngine> engine;
  ArrayFactory factory;

  void throwError(std::string errorMessage) {
    engine->feval(matlab::engine::convertUTF8StringToUTF16String("error"),
            0, std::vector<Array>({ factory.createScalar(errorMessage) }));
  }

  uint64_t write_shared_memory(const std::string & name, const std::string & value) {
    try {
      shared_memory_object sm(open_only,  name.c_str(), read_write);
      mapped_region sh_mem(sm, read_write);
      uint64_t size = std::min(value.size(), sh_mem.get_size());
      std::memcpy(sh_mem.get_address(), value.c_str(), size);
      return size;
    } catch(std::exception & e) {
      throwError(std::string("Reading error: ") + std::string(e.what()));
    }
    return 0;
  }

  void checkArguments(matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs, matlab::mex::ArgumentList outputs) {
    if (inputs.size() != 2)
      throwError("Input must be of size 2");
    if (inputs[0].getType() != ArrayType::CHAR)
      throwError("First element must be a matlab char array");
    if (inputs[1].getType() != ArrayType::CHAR)
      throwError("Second element must be a matlab char array to save");
    if (outputs.size() > 1)
      throwError("Too many outputs (required 1)");
  }

public:
  MexFunction() { 
    engine = getEngine();
  }

  void operator()(matlab::mex::ArgumentList outputs, matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs) {  
    checkArguments(inputs, outputs);
    const CharArray name_array = std::move(inputs[0]);
    std::string name = name_array.toAscii();
    const CharArray value_array = std::move(inputs[1]);
    std::string value = value_array.toAscii();
    uint64_t written = write_shared_memory(name, value);
    outputs[0] = factory.createScalar<uint64_t>(written);
  }  
};
```

The last mex is the most complex and handles the creation and deletion of the shared memory. You will notice the presence of a destructor that  handles the removal of shared memory when the mex is unloaded from Matlab. The interface takes a command in the form of `"create"` or `"delete"`, a string with the name of the share and the size of the shared memory for creation (it must be an unsigned int - `uint16(...)`). The function returns the size of the shared memory (it should be equal to size):

```
function size_shmem = menage_mex(command, share_name, uint16(size))
  ...
end
```

the implementation is the following:

```
// File: menage_share.cpp
#include "mex.hpp"
#include "mexAdapter.hpp"
#include "MatlabDataArray.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>

#include "boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp"
#include "boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp"

using namespace boost::interprocess;
using namespace matlab::data;

class MexFunction : public matlab::mex::Function {
private:
  std::shared_ptr<matlab::engine::MATLABEngine> engine;
  ArrayFactory factory;
  std::vector<std::string> pool; 

  void throwError(std::string errorMessage) {
    engine->feval(matlab::engine::convertUTF8StringToUTF16String("error"),
            0, std::vector<Array>({ factory.createScalar(errorMessage) }));
  }

  uint64_t run_command(const std::string & cmd, const std::string & name, uint64_t size) {
    if (cmd == "create")
      return create_shared_memory(name, size);       
    if (cmd == "delete")
      return delete_shared_memory(name, size);

    throwError("The command is unknown");
    return 0;
  }

  uint64_t create_shared_memory(const std::string & name, uint64_t size) {
    bool in_pool = false;
    for (const auto & el : pool) {
      if (el == name) {
        in_pool = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (in_pool) {
      try {
        shared_memory_object sm(open_only, name.c_str(), read_only);
        mapped_region sm_reg(sm, read_only);
        if (sm_reg.get_size() != size)
          throwError("Memory already exist and it is of different size");
        return 0;
      } catch (std::exception & e) {
        throwError(std::string("Cannot open existing shared memory (maybe already open?) :: ") + std::string(e.what()));
      }
    } else {
      try {
        shared_memory_object sm(create_only, name.c_str(), read_write);
        sm.truncate(size);
        pool.push_back(name);
        return size;
      } catch (std::exception & e) {
        throwError(std::string("Cannot create shared memory [" + name + "] (maybe already open?) :: ") + std::string(e.what()));
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }

  uint64_t delete_shared_memory(const std::string & name, uint64_t size) {
    std::size_t in_pool = 0; 
    for (const auto & el : pool) {
      if (el == name)
        break;
      in_pool++;
    }
    if (in_pool < pool.size()) {
      shared_memory_object::remove(name.c_str());
      pool.erase(pool.begin() + in_pool);
    } else {
      throwError("Shared memory [" + name + "] is not handled by this mex");
    }
    return 0;
  }

  void checkArguments(matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs, matlab::mex::ArgumentList outputs) {
    if (inputs.size() != 3)
      throwError("Input must be of size 3");
    if (inputs[0].getType() != ArrayType::CHAR)
      throwError("First element must be a matlab char array");
    if (inputs[1].getType() != ArrayType::CHAR)
      throwError("Second element must be amatlab char array");
    if (inputs[2].getType() != ArrayType::UINT64)
      throwError("Third element must be a single uint64 integer");
    if (outputs.size() > 1)
      throwError("Too many outputs (required 1)");
  }

  void inputArguments(std::string & cmd, std::string & name, uint64_t & size, matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs) {
    const CharArray cmd_array = std::move(inputs[0]);
    const CharArray name_array = std::move(inputs[1]);
    const TypedArray<uint64_t> size_array = std::move(inputs[2]);
    cmd = cmd_array.toAscii();
    name = name_array.toAscii();
    size = size_array[0];
  }

public:
  MexFunction() { 
    pool.clear(); 
    engine = getEngine();
  }

  ~MexFunction() {
    for (const auto & el : pool) {
      shared_memory_object::remove(el.c_str());
    }
  }

  void operator()(matlab::mex::ArgumentList outputs, matlab::mex::ArgumentList inputs) {  
    checkArguments(inputs, outputs);

    std::string cmd, name;
    uint64_t size;
    inputArguments(cmd, name, size, inputs);
    uint64_t ret = run_command(cmd, name, size);
    outputs[0] = factory.createScalar<uint64_t>(ret);
  }  
};
```

To compile the mex you can use the following script:

```
MEX_OPT = ['-I', '/path/to/boost'];

MEX_SRC = { ...
  'menage_share.cpp', ...
  'read_share.cpp', ...
  'write_share.cpp' ...
};

for i = 1:length(MEX_SRC)
  mex(MEX_OPT, MEX_SRC{i});
end

!g++ share_server.cpp -o share_server
```

and you can test them as follows:

```
(MATLAB)                                        | (TERMINAL)
>> menage_share('create', 'shmem', uint64(20))  | 
<< 20                                           |
>> write_share('shmem', 'Hello there')          | $ ./share_server
<< 11                                           |   ( ... help message ... )
                                                | << r
                                                | >> Hello there
```

Comment: According to my understanding,the concept which you have shared is sharing the data through boost memory mapped region ,but here I'm using managed shared memory which has segments for sharing the data.But the problem is not with  the sharing of data. When I try to debug the application after mexing it ,it throws the above mentioned exception when this particular line is called "managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "share_data", 65535);" so how do I resolve it ? and When I checked the call stack I could notice that only the boost API's are causing the trouble.

Comment: check the answer again, now you have everything to go in both directions

Comment: I tried compiling the above code by using the script in Matlab R2017a, but mex.hpp was missing. So I tried running the same code with Matlab R2018a ,then the compiler prompted a linker error telling that unable to find boost_date_time-vc120-mt-1_55.lib .This library is not available in this installed boost package ,because this boost library only supports msvc2012 compiler and not msvc2013.

Comment: The C++ interface is introduced in 2018a, thus it is correct that `mex.hpp` is not available. Shared memory is header only and doesn't need linking (as you can see in the `mex` command above). If you are using additional stuff than you should open another question, because `date_time` is not needed for compiling the above example.

Comment: I haven't used any additional things with the above mentioned code.I have followed the above mentioned steps.I created the above mentioned 4 cpp files and a .m  file for that script which is mentioned above,when I run the script am getting this error "LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-1_55.lib' ".

Comment: I have followed the above mentioned steps like I have created 4 .cpp files and a .m file for the script ,but when I run the script am getting the following error "LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-1_55.lib' "